# NetBeans ("6.8" and "later") - UML support?

Tags: netbeans, uml

I wanted to download the "UML plugin" to NetBeans through the "Tools/Plugins" but I didn't find the plugin there. Then I read in many articles that the "NetBeans UML plugin is not supported anymore" :-( .

Then I discovered that there exists some "NetBeans SDE" tool that supports the UML in NetBeans and there exists the "Comunity Edition" of that tool which is free, but only for "non-commercial" uses - so it's not open-source - and so I don't want to use it.

So I would like to ask, if Sun (or whoever else who officially maintains (or maintained in the past) the NetBeans UML plugin) is not going to support the UML plugin to NetBeans anymore and if so, is there any "open-source" UML plugin which is supported in version "6.8" and "later" and if so - which?

Thank you.

Comment: NetBeans IDE Dev (Build 201112080600), none works. But maybe you have to keep one oldest version always. And use seperately. On the other hand there is 1.3GB sized JBuilder, which may also offer this for free.

Answer (score 3):

I had also a problem with installing UML for my NetBeans 6.8. Most of solutions proposed in the Web doesn't seem to work. Today I have finally find how to install UML plugin on NetBeans 6.8.

**Step by step explanation of the process of installation of the plugin:**

1. Go to
   http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/updates/6.7.1/uc/final/beta/modules/uml6/
   and download all .nbm files from there.
2. Open NetBeans and go to Tools->Plugins->Downloaded
3. Click on Add plugins… button
4. Select all .nbm files you have downloaded from the source mentioned above.
5. Follow step by step wizard of NetBeans to install plugins

Hope that helps you also. As for me I am enjoying UML in NetBeans starting from today. 
***Good luck.***

Comment: Is your solution working even though in your link was the version "6.7.1"?

Comment: I guess there is some problem with the link, i am unbale to download the files.

Answer (score 1):

Excerpts from the [Netbeans UML Roadmap](http://wiki.netbeans.org/UMLRoadmap) (emphasis, mine)

> 1. With the release of NetBeans 6.5, we will officially **stop all *new* feature development** on NetBeans UML
> 2. The current UML offering, ...is **enough** to satisfy the needs of most developers
> 3. We are **partnering** with Visual Paradigm .. **to provide a solution for** those who need these **additional** capabilities beyond what is provided by the NetBeans UML plugin.
> 4. NetBeans will continue to offer and **support the existing UML functionality**.

I've got 6.7 with the UML plugin installed.. not sure about 6.8